# How do I get access to a variable's property to my class if it's in another class?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Basically, I have an SKScene class called GameScene. In GameScene, I have a variable called playableArea that is calculated depending on the size of the user's phone.

I have an enemy class that needs to know the width of the playableArea, and then use that value to move to to the x position by an SKAction depending on the width of playableArea.

This is my class (simplified version):

```
class PacuPiranha: Fish {

    static var s = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PacuPiranha1")
    var width: CGFloat = 0

    struct SharedAssets {
        static var move: SKAction!
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
     }


    init(position: CGPoint, width: CGFloat) {
        self.width = width
    }

    override class func preloadAssets() -> SKTexture? {

        dispatch_once(&SharedAssets.token, {

            SharedAssets.move = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveToX(width + s.size.width, duration: 2.5), SKAction.removeFromParent()])
            return SharedAssets.texture
        }
    }
}
```

The enemy fish needs to move to the other size of the screen, but the size of the screen is determined by the size of the device the user is using, so I need to pass the width of the screen to the moveToX action which occurs in the init call. But I get the error "Instance member 'width' cannot be used on type 'PacuPiranha'."

How do I get the width of a variable that is from the GameScene class, which is where the new object of the enemy is being created?

```
let fish = PacuPiranha(position: CGPoint(...), width: playableArea.size.width)
```

I have also tried making a new function in the enemy class like this:

```
func getWidth() -> CGFloat {
    let view = scene as! GameScene
    view.playableArea.size.width
}
```

And then using getWidth() inside the moveToX, but that didn't work either since it's asking for an argument of type self: PacuPiranha.

Answer (score 0):

### Retrieving the Screen Size

You can get the screen size with this code

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
```

### My point of view

I think you are overcomplicating the code.
Wouldn't it be easier if `PacuPiranha` was a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` added to `GameScene`?

And finally, do you really need all that code to preload the resources? SpriteKit is pretty good at managing the resources, you should let it do its work unless your game specifically needs a custom approach.

### Update

**IF** `PacuPiranha` was a `SKSpriteNode` subclass (as it should be) added to the the SKScene you would be able to use this code to get the size of the current view.

```
class PacuPiranha: SKSpriteNode {

    func foo() {
        if let viewSize = self.scene?.view?.frame {
            print(viewSize)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm using this approach is because the game spawns a lot of these sprites at once and instead of loading different ones into memory and their actions, this saves memory a lot better since it loads it once and uses it for all objects created from this class. My original approach was an SKSpriteNode but I was converting all the fish into classes.

Comment: If you want to cache `SKActions`, i suggest you to use the Xcode Level Editor.  It has a specific function to define an action via GUI that can be easily retrieved via code.

Comment: But what I have already works. I'm only having trouble with this class because the fish moves from the left to the right. With the other classes, it was easier because they move from right to left. All I had to do was use moveToX(-sprite.size.width...)

Comment: Also, I've never liked using UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width because the values are wrong. If I use that, the fish won't move across the device, it will move about in the middle of the screen and stop, which it shouldn't.

Comment: @JozemiteApps: Please see my update. I told you, you should use SpriteKit as it is supposed to be used. I would't care about this level of optimization in this early stage of development. You are free to choose how to develop your game but using a tool in the wrong way could be worst that not having the tool at all.

Comment: It's not an early stage, it's an update. The game is already in the App Store, it's called Chomp'd. It works fine, but on older devices, it sometimes lags which is why I started making the fish into objects and preload the data only once and that's it. It's improved the game's memory. Whether my approach is wrong or not, it still doesn't answer the actual question, how do I get access to a variable's property that is outside the class from another class

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice what you meant earlier. PacuPiranha is a subclass of Fish which is a subclass of SKSpriteNode.

Comment: @JozemiteApps: Ok, then after the instance of `PacuPiranha` has been added to the scene, you can run `self.scene?.view?.frame` to get the size of the view.

Answer (score 0):

`UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` Will give you the screens width in pixels.

Comment: I've don't like that code because it never works right. It says that the width and height of my device is 736 and 414... which it isn't since it's an iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: The playableArea variable I use calculates the correct view of the screen that the player can see, which says its 2048x1152. The UIScreen code says its 736x414.

Comment: You are comparing two different things there. The UIScreen is giving you the size of the screen in points witch are not the same as pixels where as your measurement of 2048x1152 is pixels. They do this so that you do not have to do device specific code there is a property on UIScreen called `Scale` which you can access witch will tell you how much the screen is scaled if you need that.